# CPU frequency is very low and system is very slow too in core i5 vaio laptop

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, cpu-usage, sony-vaio, cpu-speed

Sometimes I notice that system is very slow and when I see task manager, these are information in performance tab:

```
Utilization: 8%
Speed: 0.2 Ghz
Maxsimum speed: 2.5 GHz
```

Hardware details are:

```
Windows 8 Pro x64
Sony vaio vpcse23fx
core i5 2450M
RAM 8 GB
VGA Intel gen2 hd 3000
ATI 7400 series
HDD 5400 rpm
```

As an aside, my graphics driver is from leshcatlabs.net (updated and joined drivers for Intel and ATI).
I use this driver because last update of Sony's driver is 2012 and original ATI's driver from AMD has some problems.
I also disabled ATI card in device manager but problem occurred again. Is it possible that this problem be related to VGA?

Please note, this slow issue occurs at least once every 2 hours, but only lasts a period of time.

What do I mean by slow? It is slow when I want to open an app, when I move mouse (moves with some lags), when I open task manager, when I switch tabs in chrome, even slow in network. Also copying and moving files.

It's obviously related to frequency, because when frequency backs to 2 GHz everything acts normally again.

How can I fix this annoying speed issue?

**Update:** I found that this issue occures only when laptop uses Intel VGA, And instantly after switching to ATI card frequency goes back to 2GHz.

Distance between frequency issue occurences in my tests is under 1 minute! I mean after switching graphics card to Intel, It happens after less than a minute and switching to ATI fixes it instantly.

---

**Solved:** 
By using amd.com driver and `drivermax` for updating intel driver problem totally solved and after some months of this update i have not this problem again.

Comment: Speed of cpu. frequency of cpu is 0.2 ~ 0.4 GHz. This isn't normal speed when everything in laptop is slow.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, because you mention the graphics card, does the slow issue happen only with video/animations? Is it quick booting up but slow using certain applications? Is it slow from booting up and using it (if so, why mentino the graphic card)

Comment: It's just a guess, i'm not professional in hardware. I just said maybe it's related to vga because it's not original sony driver.

Comment: I see. Can you explain what is slow: does the slow issue happen only with video/animations? Is it quick booting up but slow using certain applications? Is it slow from booting up?

Comment: Slow In what It is processing, copying, running apps etc..

Comment: Slow when i want to open an app, when i move mouse (moves with some lags), when i open task manager, when i switch tabs in chrome, even slow in network. also copying and moving files. it's obviously related to frequency, because when frequency backs to 2 GHz everything acts normally again.

Comment: I see, so this happens randomly - you periods of extreme slow, then it will start working again OK?

Comment: yes. but ramdomly means less than 2 hours.

Comment: I updated your question, hopefully this will help. Did you do a virus scan just to be on the safe side, and run something like malware bytes?

Comment: Thank you! Windows defender is updated and i will scan with it too now.

Comment: After 3 days with ATI enabled graphic card, there is no issue in CPU frequency. So the problem is Intel GPU and it's driver.

Answer (score 1):

Slowness on a machine can be caused not just by CPU activity but also by disk activity and I have seen this on a number of occassions. Sometimes this could be down to a background process accessing a big file.

To check your disk activity download Sysinternal's Process Monitor. When your computer is running slow then run the utility for I would say no more than a minute (more than that is not really necessary).

When you've completed your trace, do a count for the number of times each file was being accessed during that the trace you captured. To do this, go to to Tools -> Count Values Occurences -> Select Path from the Column drop-down and then click on the Count button. Click the Count button to sort the count numbers in ascending/descending order and it should become clear which files are being heavily accessed. Double-click on any of those file paths to focus on them and see which programs are responsible for the disk access.

Comment: I tried this and answer is Explorer.exe that's triying to read from registry. "Process name: Explorer.exe, PID:3936, Operation:RegQueryKey,  Path:HKCU\Software\Classes, Result:Success, Detail:Query Handle Tags". Is this results normal? @user319647

Comment: In another test (this time in normal situation of cpu) result was completely different. This time many applications was on result (counted and filtered) but in previous test (in low frequency) 99% of processes in result was Explorer.exe.

Comment: HKCU\Software\Classes by itself isn't an issue: I think Explorer is drilling through the registry hierarchy which is why you see it there. When your machine slows again can you run the trace for a minute. Do a count using my instructions and note the top 10 file paths being accessed. List those 10 paths here with the number of times being accessed and I'll have a look.

As a side note, how much CPU is Explorer.exe taking up during slowness?

Comment: See this image for the list: http://imgur.com/b8Se9sN

Comment: Explorer.exe cpu usage is less than 1%

Comment: If explorer.exe is less than 1% then we can ignore that. I only asked because of a previous experience with explorer.exe. I had a look at the image you uploaded. Here's my findings. Total number of events you captured is 11068. The events that caught my attention refer to your E: drive and to something called jade. The most significant file path with 1189 events was E:\www\nik\office-checkin\node_modules\gulp\mode_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob2base\node_modules\... Another with 755 events was HKCU\Software\Classes\jade_auto_file. Then another with 216 events was..

Comment: ..E:\www\nik\office-checkin\views\404.jade. I suspect this is some development environment you have on your machine. You can filter on those events by double-clicking on those file paths and see what they are doing.

Comment: Yes, jade files and everything in node_modules folders are some development related files and they are safe. I had run nodejs local server on my machine. So i should search for other possible ways like bad drivers?

Comment: Yes, understand that they might be safe but you'd still have to check them out as they are reason for all the activity on your machine whilst it is experiencing slowness. Your picture says it. Filter on them and see what they are doing. It may be down to a configuration or a bug of whatever but don't assume that just because they are safe that you can ignore them.

Comment: After some other occurences i found that instantly after switching graphic card to ATI manually, frequency goes back to normal 2GHz. So i'm sure it's related to graphic's card and it's driver. But i don't know which driver can solve this. I had some blue screens and by installing driver from amd's website there is no blue screen up to now but frequency issue occured again.